# Convert alphanumeric to Mnemonic?

Tags: coinbase.com, mnemonic-seed

I have found here at home a paper with "coinbase seed" label from the far paste. I totally forget it, and I would check the wallet, but it is not the 12 word Mnemonic, but 16 alphanumeric character. How could I convert back to the memnonic? :)

I checked here, but there is no converter:

https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Answer (score 1):

The 16 alphanumeric characters will be your 2FA recovery code. It isn't a seed for a wallet. You will need to log in to your account on Coinbase to retrieve the coins.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an entropy, encoded in ASCII

or the BIP39 passphrase, to be combined with a mnemonic stored separately